# Global settings for telerik mvc grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

Is there any way that i can set some formatting such as
   scrollable, width height  of grid at application level that are applied to all the grids in the application so that  I could avoid
   changing every grid in application

Answer (score 5):

You can create a custom extension method for `HtmlHelper` and configure the grid there. Use that method instead. Here is some sample code:

```
public static class GridHtmlHelperExtensions
{        
        public static GridBuilder<T> Grid<T>(this HtmlHelper html) 
            where T : class
        {
            var builder = html.Telerik().Grid<T>();

            builder.Pageable();
            builder.Sortable();

            return builder;
        }
}
```

And then in your view:

```
<%: Html.Grid<MyModel>().Name("MyGrid") %>
```